# Building a Function to automate tabulation

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to build a function to tabulate table building. Essentially, if I have a bunch of categorical variables, I want to be able to just tabulate them with counts & percentages without doing each one individually. I have most of the code down but am having issues with the loop. Basically, I want a table with all the variables & the corresponding counts & percentages displayed. My loop is looping through but only displaying the final variable. See code below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
descriptives <- function(VARIABLEMATRIX){
for (i in 1:ncol(VARIABLEMATRIX)){
matper <- matrix(0, nrow=dim(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i])), ncol=1)
for (i in 1:dim(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i]))){
matper[i, ] <- paste(round(prop.table(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i]))[i]*100, 2), "%")
}

matcount <- matrix(0, nrow=dim(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i])), ncol=1)
for (i in 1:dim(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i]))){
matcount[i, ] <- table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i])[i]
}

space <- matrix(c(colnames(VARIABLEMATRIX)[i], "", "", ""), ncol=4, nrow=1)
desc <- cbind("", names(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i])), matcount[ ,1], matper[ ,1])
desc <- rbind(space, desc)
return(desc)
}
}
```

The play dataset is here:

```
ESRD <- rep(c("Y", "N"), each=10)
DIABETES <- rep(c("Y", "N", "Y", "N"), c(5, 5, 5, 5))
categoricalvariables <- cbind(ESRD, DIABETES)
```

What I'm finally getting is this :

```
descriptives(categoricalvariables)
     [,1]       [,2] [,3] [,4]  
[1,] "DIABETES" ""   ""   ""    
[2,] ""         "N"  "10" "50 %"
[3,] ""         "Y"  "10" "50 %"
```

The desired output would be along the lines of:

```
descriptives(categoricalvariables)
[,1]       [,2] [,3] [,4]  
"ESRD"     ""   ""   "" 
""         "N"  "10" "50 %"
""         "Y"  "10" "50 %"
"DIABETES" ""   ""   ""    
""         "N"  "10" "50 %"
""         "Y"  "10" "50 %"
```

Comment: What is the desired output for this input?

Comment: Are you aware of the existing `table()` function? Do you really want to dump all this data into a character matrix?

Comment: I am aware of table - notice I've used it. I am tired of typing table(DATASET$VARIABLENAME) for the 10-20 variables that I have to present descriptive statistics for every day at work. I want to build a function like the one above so I can then just create one large table with all the variables & then export to pdf/word using xtable